# Trouble with Include extension on IObjectSet not working

Tags: entity-framework

Could anyone help me in assessing why the code below doesn't work.  I'm using the common extension method for implementing Include when using IObjectset.  In our repositories we were seeing this not returning correctly so I've isolated the code in test app as below.  I've also included the interface based Context if this may prove relevant and a screenshot of the relevant model section.  This occurs for all Includes on IObjectSet properties not just the DPASelections one I've chosen for this example.

If I update the context to return ObjectSet (still using the POCO entities) rather than IObjectSet it all works fine.  When using IObjectSet and the extension method and step through the code I see that the extension method is completing correctly with a call to the ObjectQuery we're casting to but the included entities are never returned on the graph.  As said, this works perfectly when I don't interface out the Context and return ObjectSet properties hence calling Include directly on ObjectSet.

I'm not getting any errors on executing the query so this isn't the same as several other questions on SO which refer to compiled queries.

Has anyone else experienced problems with this extension method implementation or can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here?

Any help very much appreciated.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var context = new AssocEntities())
        {
            context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            Candidate candidate = context.Candidates
                                        .Include("DPASelections.DPAOption")
                                        .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Number == "N100064");

            //Count is 0 when using ext. method and IObjectSet through AssocContext but correct when using Include
            //on ObjectSet through AssocContext
            Console.WriteLine("DPASelection count = {0}",candidate.DPASelections.Count);

            //This is always null when using IObjectSet and ext. method but populated
            //when using Include on ObjectSet
            var option = candidate.DPASelections.First().DPAOption;

            Console.WriteLine("First DPAOption = {0} : {1}",option.Id,option.Text);

        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TSource> Include<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, string path)
    {
        var objectQuery = source as ObjectQuery<TSource>;

        if (objectQuery != null)
        {
            objectQuery.Include(path);
        }

        return source;
    }
}

//Subset of custom context implementing IObjectSet as returns.
//Works fine when I return ObjectSet rather than IObjectSet and use
//the Include method directly
public partial class AssocEntities : ObjectContext
{
    public const string ConnectionString = "name=AssocEntities";
    public const string ContainerName = "AssocEntities";

    #region Constructors

    public AssocEntities()
        : base(ConnectionString, ContainerName)
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    public AssocEntities(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString, ContainerName)
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    public AssocEntities(EntityConnection connection)
        : base(connection, ContainerName)
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IObjectSet Properties

    public IObjectSet<Address> Addresses
    {
        get { return _addresses ?? (_addresses = CreateObjectSet<Address>("Addresses")); }
    }
    private IObjectSet<Address> _addresses;

    public IObjectSet<Answer> Answers
    {
        get { return _answers ?? (_answers = CreateObjectSet<Answer>("Answers")); }
    }
    private IObjectSet<Answer> _answers;

    public IObjectSet<Candidate> Candidates
    {
        get { return _candidates ?? (_candidates = CreateObjectSet<Candidate>("Candidates")); }
    }
}
```

And the model...
[image]

Comment: i've used the exact same setup, and it works fine for me (doesnt really help you, but thought id mention that). have you stepped through the code - is your extension method called, have you run profiler trace, etc..

Comment: Ext. method code runs fine and calls into the DB but the query produced just ignores the Includes and only returns the Candidate.

Comment: @Daz Lewis - did you try `.Include("DPASelections").Include("DPASelections.DPAOption")` i don't think you can go straight to a double-nested nav. (i could be wrong). keep it simple, does `context.Candidates.Include("Grade").FirstOrDefault()` work?

Comment: BTW - when you reply to comments on SO, put the person's alias in the comment - e.g @RPM1984, as that way i will get notified. I didn't get notified of your above comment. Just a hint.

Comment: @RPM1984 - None of my Includes work when using the extension method.  In my test app they also don't work even if I use ObjectSet on the context and try and create the includes off an array using a foreach.  The "DPASelections.DPAOption" works fine when I go direct against Include on the ObjectSet with a single string.  Losing the will to live here with this one!  BTW - thanks for the tip on @ marking the comment.

Comment: Hmm. Well i do the same thing with Include. I pass through a string[], then do .Include for each item. If your saying it doesnt even work with ObjectSet, i think the problem is with your includes. Let me ask you this: if you write the query: `var query = db.Candidates.Include("Grade").FirstOrDefault()` - does it work? Does "Grade" get populated?? (no mocking of ObjectContext, just a simple eager load).

Comment: @RPM1984 It works fine in that scenario.  Everything works fine until I try and introduce the extension method, whether it takes an array or just a single string the ex method executes but the result always fails to return the included associations.

Comment: That's bizarre, it's the same code. It should go in, do the cast, then do include.

Comment: Figured it out! I needed to replace objectQuery.Include(path); with objectQuery = objectQuery.Include(path);

Comment: Lolz - i didn't even notice that with your code. Include returns an IQueryable, but since your not assigning it to anything nothing happened. Hehe. Good thing i copied my extension method straight from Julie Lerman's book. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to replace `objectQuery.Include(path);` with `objectQuery = objectQuery.Include(path);`

Answer (score 0):

In .Net framework 4.0 there is a build-in Extentionmethod for `Include`
just add the `System.Data.Entity` namespace.

It uses reflection - here is how it works:

```
private static T CommonInclude<T>(T source, string path)
{
  MethodInfo method = source.GetType().GetMethod("Include", DbExtensions.StringIncludeTypes);
  if (!(method != (MethodInfo) null) || !typeof (T).IsAssignableFrom(method.ReturnType))
    return source;
  return (T) method.Invoke((object) source, new object[1]
  {
    (object) path
  });
}
```